# Provider id in smpp

Tags: smpp

I am currently integrating with a new client over smpp that is requesting that I pass back the same provider id that they provide me with.

I have gone through all the documentation and done extensive research on the subject but I can't find anything where provider id is part of smpp.

The example I have is as follows

I think that this is submitted via a soap api

originating message:

```
<messages><message address="xxxxxxxxxx" id="13001" noRetry="false" providerId="xx96xxxx157" status="9"/></messages>
```

When I send back the reply to the message I am also "seem" to be passing provider id

reply message:

```
`<messages index="3"><message alias="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" message="xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx" origin="xxxxxxxxxx" providerId="8xxxxx7-1xx0-xxx9-xx1b-xxxxxxxx34"/></messages>`
```

The above is from my clients logs, none of this is in my pdus

My Question is does this form part of smpp and if so where can I find the provider id?

Thanks

Comment: this has nothing to do with smpp

Comment: Thank you I thought as much